# Not able to deploy in Azure Production Slot

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-deployment-slots

I have a Linux Virtual Machine, I am able to deploy the app in the cloud service staging slot but not able to deploy it in the production. I am deploying the app through Eclipse, getting the following error

> Failed : BadRequest: This operation cannot be performed on a
>   deployment containing virtual machines.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy a Java based `Cloud Service` in a Linux VM?

Comment: Yes. Deploying the war using the Azure Toolkit plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to deploy a `Cloud Service` application in a Virtual Machine. A `Cloud Service` deployment will create its own VMs and then deploy the code there. I believe you're getting this error because you're trying to mix PaaS with IaaS.

Comment: But I am able to deploy it in the staging slot. So which is the right way to deploy to the virtual machine IaaS

Comment: This could be because the staging slot is empty when you tried to deploy the app. If I understand your question correctly, then I don't think it is possible to deploy your application in a Virtual Machine. Either you would need to change your application type and make it a regular application or delete that Linux Virtual Machine from production slot and then deploy your Cloud Service there.

Comment: Please note that VMs in which Cloud Services are deployed have Windows OS and not Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on logging and troubleshoot it by getting details from FTP.

Also, if you are using slots, the native deployment procedure is just a swap between Stage slot and Production slot. It will be done very quickly.

Comment: I tried swapping earlier in the portal. I am getting the following error when I swap, "The production and staging slot IP addresses for cloudservice_name could not be swapped."